# How to batch rename files in Windows and swapping the first word in the filename with the second?

Tags: regex, file, rename

I have multiple business contact files (.vcf) like the following:

```
Bloggs Joe.vcf
Smith John.vcf
...
```

How can I bulk rename all the files and switch the order of the first word in the filename with the second?  e.g.

```
Joe Bloggs.vcf
John Smith.vcf
...
```

I'm using Windows at the moment but can easily switch to OSX or a Linux distro if it would make it easier to accomplish.

Kind regards,

Comment: Have you tried anything? What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the below `rename` command on the directory where `.vcf` files are located. All linux ditros comes with `rename` utility.

```
rename 's/^(\w+)\s+(\w+)/\2 \1/' *.vcf
```

Comment: It worked great, thanks.  The only problem I had was if the surname was double-barreled or they had a third word such as a qualification in there, but it worked perfectly for Surname Forename.vcf

Comment: try `rename 's/^(\w+(?:-\w+)?)\s+(\w+(?:-\w+)?)/\2 \1/' *.vcf`